# How to translate blog tools from English to German? sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, css

Is there any change to translate the blog tools from English to German or to another language?

I have the following tools;
[image]

Comment: in which language your base SharePoint Installed, English? do you have any language pack install, German?

Comment: yes it is English; but i want to translate only blog tools not the entire SharePoint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far I Know, you can get this if you install the extra language pack for German or other languages. You can't just change it for blogs tool even with LPs.

> when you create a site collection or a site and select a language, the
>   user interface text that appears on the site collection or site is
>   shown in the selected language. For example, when you create a site in
>   French, the toolbars, navigation bars, lists, and column headings for
>   that site appear in French. Likewise, if you create a site in Arabic,
>   the site administration pages and user interface, such as toolbars,
>   navigation bars, lists, and column headings for that site, appear in
>   Arabic, and the default left-to-right orientation of the site changes
>   to a right-to-left orientation to correctly show Arabic text.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262055.aspx#BKMK_langpack